# Next.js 13.5.3: HTML Elements with 'hidden' Class Not Displaying with 'md:flex' for Desktop View

Tags: tailwind-css, next.js13

I recently updated my Next.js application to version 13.5.3 and encountered an issue where HTML elements with the 'hidden' class, which are supposed to be hidden by default, are not displaying as expected. I've also applied the 'md:flex' class for desktop view, but the elements remain hidden. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this visibility problem in the updated Next.js version.

```
 <h1 className="text-base sm:text-[18px] w-max font-semibold hidden md:flex">
  Logo
 </h1>
```

The logo is not showing at all

```
 <div className="hidden md:flex gap-8">
              {routes.map((route) => (
                <Link
                  href={route.href}
                  key={route.href}
                  className={cn(
                    "text-muted-foreground text-md group flex w-full justify-start font-medium cursor-pointer hover:text-white rounded-lg transition",
                    pathname === route.href && "bg-primary/10 text-white"
                  )}
                >
                  {route.label}
                </Link>
              ))}
            </div>
```

even though am on desktop view it is still hidden

If i remove the hidden class it appears

Comment: It works as expected https://play.tailwindcss.com/QDnE8KMdFQ

Comment: Yes, it was working as expected when using next 13.4.19, but when I upgraded to 13.5.3 all the classes that has hidden are hidden no matter the screen size